# How do I retrieve the related models of related models in many-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, database, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

Is the question clear? Basically I have these tables:

```
|------------|                      |-----------------|
| Group      |                      | Student-Subject |
|------------|                      |-----------------|
| id         |                      | id              |
| group_name |                      | student_id      |
|------------|                      | subject_id      |                      
                                    |-----------------|

                            |--------------|    |--------------|
                            | Student      |    | Subject      |
                            |--------------|    |--------------|
                            | id           |    | id           |
                            | student_name |    | subject_name |
                            | group_id     |    |--------------|
                            |--------------|
```

If I had to explain the relationship (it's pretty obvious, but to be clear), the student has many subjects  and the subject has many students. They are connected through the Student-Subject table.

In addition to this, the students are grouped. They are connected to the group table by their group_id fields.

Now, I what I want to achieve is, I want to get the subjects for the group model. Basically, I want to get all of the subjects of all students in the group. Of course I already have my own solution:

```
SELECT subject.id, subject.subject_name
FROM tbl_student_subject studsubj 
LEFT JOIN tbl_student student ON student.id = studsubj.student_id
RIGHT JOIN tbl_subject subject ON subject.id = studsubj.subject_id
WHERE student.group_id = 1
```

[image: This is the sample result.]

If you observe the picture, which is the result of the query, the subjects are duplicated. I think this is enough for now, but of course I don't want them duplicated.

So, what I'm trying to achieve by asking this question is, how do I get the results without duplication? Am I doing this right with my SQL Script?

While I'm at this, I wanted to do this in Laravel Eloquent model. But it's not achievable using the "hasManyThrough" method. If possible, I will use this raw SQL to do what I'm trying to achieve.

I hope anyone understands and be able to answer my question and correct my script. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried "SELECT DISTINCT..." ?

Comment: I haven't yet. I only did basic SQL. I'll try to learn that.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT subject.id, subject.subject_name FROM tbl_student_subject studsubj LEFT JOIN tbl_student student ON student.id = studsubj.student_id RIGHT JOIN tbl_subject subject ON subject.id = studsubj.subject_id WHERE student.group_id = 1

Comment: It's simple to try it. You just need to add "DISTINCT" in your current query just after "SELECT" :)

Comment: I think it worked as intended. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple answer. I just had to add DISTINCT in the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT subject.id, subject.subject_name 
FROM tbl_student_subject studsubj 
LEFT JOIN tbl_student student ON student.id = studsubj.student_id 
RIGHT JOIN tbl_subject subject ON subject.id = studsubj.subject_id 
WHERE student.group_id = 1
```